# Don't save in Database if before exist on laravel 5.4

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have a form that want create category for my posts,and other  categories are in tag table,Now I Want when I add new category that exist I receive this error and return back How I can do this?my form to create new category has this code:

```
 <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="/tag">
       {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" >New Category:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And my Controller to Add category has this code:

```
  public function store(request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,array('name'=>'required'));
    $tag=new Tag;
    $tag->name=$request->name;
    $tag->save();
    return redirect('/tag');
}
```

Comment: Thanks!please check My question

Comment: have you tried to put 'array('name'=>'required|unique ')

Comment: Add this code in validation?

Comment: yes, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to see this rule?
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-unique

in the doc example:

```
$v = Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => 'unique:users,email_address'
]);
```

In your scenario could be:

```
$valid = Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => 'unique:table'
]);
```

and if you can check if there is an error with `$valid->fails()` and you could print with `$valid->errors()->all()`

So, after put vcalidation in your $this->validate() function and return if there is errors you can do something like:

```
$validation = $this->validate($request,array('name'=>'required|unique:table_name'));
if($validation->valid){
 ...
 }else{ 
 //what you want like:
       redirect('route')->withErrors(["errors"=>$validation->errors])
 }
```

And your function validate could be somethiong like this:

```
private function validate($data , $rules){
  $valid = Validator::make($data, $rules);
  $result = new /StdClass();
  $result->valid = !$valid->fails();
  $result->errors = $valid->errors()->all()
  return $result
}
```

Comment: How I Can See Error of exist?

Comment: the unique validation return error if the value exist see link to doc that I pasted. If you want print errors you can print $valid->errors()->all() for all error in your validation.

Comment: Thanks!please tell me how I add  `$valid=validatore::make` in my Code?

Comment: I have made an example how you can use the validation.